# Command that is not found in Mac os Terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

I am trying to install mySQL on macOS Mojave. I have installed mySQL Community Server 8.0.17 and then attempted to configure the command line to recognize mySQL commands by using the following code in Terminal:

```
echo ‘export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Followed by:

```
.~/.bash_profile
```

After entering this last line of code, I get the following message:

```
-bash: ‘export: command not found
```

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this problem. I'm new to coding, so I'm not sure how to rectify this error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in:

```
echo ‘.......’ >> ~/.bash_profile
```

in your quotes. Seems you are using TextEdit app or Notes app which by default translate  normal quotes

```
'
```

into

```
’
```

So this will work for you:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: In addition, `.~/.bash_profile` should be `. ~/.bash_profile` (note a space).

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Anton, I have used the command that you provided beginning with "echo" and this seems to work. However, on the course website that I am using, I am told to follow this command with a second command, `-bash: .~/.bash_profile`. When doing so, I now get another error message: `-bash: .~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory`. Amadan, I tried your suggestion and I get the error message I've provided in my OP. (`-bash: ‘export: command not found`). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ryp you already had run your previous echo command with wrong quotes. so it it is in your ~/.bash_profile now.  so whenever you will run `. ~/.bash_profile` it will complain for `‘export: command not found`. Now you need manually edit the `~/.bash_profile` file to remove the wrong line from it. You can do it with vim or nano or mcedit. After that execute correct `echo ......` command. Then your `. ~/.bash_profile` should work